# Get exact Tag name of closest git Tag

Tags: git

I'd like to find the name of the tag *closest* to the commit I specify. `git describe x` works great. But this returns an extended formatting that I'd like to get rid of. *I want the actual tag name.*

eg. `Release/v2.0.0.11-12-g17d232a`

I was writing all sorts of parsing rules splitting on dashes, but there is no guarantee the tagname can't also have dashes. And the extra metadata doesn't show up if the tag is on the commit.

So is there some hidden git voodoo that gives me the tagname?

Comment: I need this so I can find all the changes from a commit to the last build on the branch. `git log "oldtag".."branchname" --oneline` I'm writing a script that will be full automated and scrape the results.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such flag.  However, you can use `git rev-parse` to determine whether the output is actually a tag, or is a tag with modifiers:

```
$ git describe
v2.9.0-137-gcf4c2cf
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name v2.9.0-137-gcf4c2cf
$ git checkout v2.9.0
Note: checking out 'v2.9.0'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 05219a1... Git 2.9
$ git describe
v2.9.0
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name v2.9.0
refs/tags/v2.9.0
```

So if `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name` emits a symbolic full name, what you have is actually a tag.  If not, you must have one of those annoying `git describe` pseudo-tags.

(Note that `git rev-parse`, and therefore every Git command that needs a revision, will turn the pseudo-tags into commit IDs.)

**Edit**: example shell script using `expr`:

```
#! /bin/sh
# strip "git describe" output of "-<digits>-g<abbrevhash>" iff
# such a suffix seems to be present
case $# in 0) usage;; esac # define usage() yourself
for arg do
    if [ -n "$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name "$arg")" ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$arg"
    else
        expr "$arg" : '\(.*\)-[0-9]*-g[0-9a-f]*$'
    fi
done
```

(very lightly tested)

Comment: I know its going to be pseudo-tag. I just want to reliably chop off the end part.

Comment: So, use the above method to detect whether it's an actual tag or one of these "describe" tags.  If it *is* a "describe tag" or "pseudo-tag" or whatever we want to call these things, then it has two bits on the end that you must strip off: a literal `-`, a numeric value, a literal `-g`, and an alphanumeric value from the `[0-9a-f]` set. Use any regexp parser (built in to various languages, or use the `expr` command) to match and remove that.  (Or cheap out and strip `-.*-.*$`.)

Answer (score 0):

'git describe --long` will always show the extra metadata. Then one can use a regular expression to grab the end bit off.